# How do I list all files on my system with a particular timestamp?

Tags: find, timestamps

I'm running a Linux From Scratch system and I'd like to list all files with a particular timestamp, as a way of listing files belonging to a package. Is this possible? I see there are a few questions on Unix & Linux SE related to finding files with a timestamp *newer* than a particular timestamp, but I want to find files with a timestamp *equal* to a particular timestamp. Is this possible?

Comment: This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

Comment: You can try to convert the timestamp to a date and then work with it , it's gonna be much easier to deal with dates then with timestamps

Comment: If you mean drop the specific time (e.g. 00:52 for 12:52 am), just leaving the date (e.g. 2017-10-12) then that won't be helpful.

Comment: What's the timestamp precision ? Seconds (e.g. find all files modified between `00:52:00` and `00:52:59` on a certain date) or nanoseconds (e.g. find all files modified between `00:52:00.000000000`  and `00:52:59.999999999` on a certain date) or do you want to find files with `mtime` that matches exactly a certain timestamp e.g. `00:52:59.074312218` ?

Comment: Just minutes will do.

Comment: In that case it's still a range so e.g. to find files with `mtime` of `2017-10-08 00:53` run `find . -type f -newermt '2017-10-08 00:53:00' ! -newermt '2017-10-08 00:53:59'` or with `zsh` run `autoload age` and `print -rl **/*(.De_'age 2017/10/08:00:53:00 2017/10/08:00:53:59'_)`... not posting an answer as this has been already asked&answered several times...

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question. Run:

```
find . -path ./proc -prune -o \
       -path ./sources -prune -o \
       -path ./sys -prune -o \
       -path ./dev -prune -o \
       -ls | grep "timestamp" | sed 's|[a-zA-Z0-9 -:]*\./|/|g'
```

the `-path ./DIR -prune -o` parts of this command trim out DIR (proc, sources sys and dev) from the command as they're not relevant. The `sed 's|[a-zA-Z0-9 -:]*\./|/|g'` removes everything from `-ls`'s output but the file's path.

Comment: May I suggest looking into `find`’s own `-ls` action — it would avoid running separate `ls` processes. You could also use `-printf` to output the timestamp and path only, which would simplify the filtering.

Comment: Depending on what his `/etc/fstab` looks like, it might be possible to replace those prune clauses with the `-xdev` option.